# IBM Integration designer issue

Tags: integration, designer

I am trying to create a web service with integration designer, but I get the following error:

```
com.ibm.websphere.sca.ServiceUnavailableException: java.nio.channels.UnresolvedAddressException at 
  com.ibm.ws.sca.internal.jaxws.handler.JaxWsPortHandler.processMessage(JaxWsPortHandler.java:564) at 
  com.ibm.ws.sca.internal.jaxws.handler.JaxWsImportHandler.processMessage(JaxWsImportHandler.java:244) at 
  com.ibm.ws.sca.internal.jaxws.handler.NativeJaxWsImportHandler.processMessage(NativeJaxWsImportHandler.java:73) at 
  com.ibm.ws.sca.internal.message.impl.MessageDispatcherImpl.processMessageWithPCI(MessageDispatcherImpl.java:785) at 
  com.ibm.ws.sca.internal.message.impl.MessageDispatcherImpl.processMessage(MessageDispatcherImpl.java:1626) at 
  com.ibm.ws.sca.internal.message.impl.ManagedMessageImpl.process(ManagedMessageImpl.java:999) at 
  com.ibm.ws.sca.uow.handler.UOWNativeWASStrategyImpl.transactionImportExport(UOWNativeWASStrategyImpl.java:455) at 
  com.ibm.ws.sca.uow.handler.JoinUOWNativeHandler.processMessage(JoinUOWNativeHandler.java:168) at 
  com.ibm.ws.sca.internal.message.impl.MessageDispatcherImpl.processMessageWithPCI(MessageDispatcherImpl.java:785) at 
  com.ibm.ws.sca.internal.message.impl.MessageDispatcherImpl.processMessage(MessageDispatcherImpl.java:1626)
```

When I use the web service with other tools, it works fine. Can anyone help me figure out what the problem is?

I'm using  IBM ID v. 8.5.0.1

Answer (score 0):

(I see this is an old post...but this seems to happen with 8.5.5 as well) I have seen this happen if you change the interface signature in any way -- adding inputs, changing underlying BO's... usually the error goes away if you uninstall the app (or the BLA) from WAS admin console and republish the app.